# Javascript .onchange limitations

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As I begin to develop more and more complicated JavaScript solutions, I wonder what sort of options JavaScript gives me to monitor changes in my environment. I've seen so many solutions that constantly ping whatever element they are wanting to monitor, but for any sort of resource heavy application (or for any case depending on the standards of the developer) that becomes bloated and too hackish to be a viable method. Which brings me to my question, "What are the limitations of JavaScript's `onchange` event?". Specifically, right now I'm trying to monitor the size of the window. Is there a way to utilize the `.onchange` event for things like this? How would you solve this?

I'm very interested to hear what everyone has to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the window can be monitored with [onresize](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onresize.asp).

The onchange event, as Rahul says, applies to fileupload, select, text and textarea. However, it only fires once focus is shifted away from the item and onto something else, and the content has changed.

Answer (score 4):

The onchange attribute is a DOM property. It is not provided by Javascript.
W3schools reports that only some elements support its use, per [their page about the onchange event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onchange.asp):

> Supported by the following HTML tags:

```
<input type="text">, <select>,
<textarea>
```

> Supported by the following JavaScript
>   objects:
>
> fileUpload, select, text, textarea

If you want to monitor the size of the window you basically have two options:
- use the onresize attribute
- set an interval that checks via polling.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this please explain what the problem is with the answer?

Comment: It wasn't me, but the problem is that you can watch for changes in the size of the window with onresize. Ie. you don't have to poll.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it's tiny and insanely powerful.

jQuery has two function that should be of use to you: [width()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width) and [height()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height)

Example (based on example from the docs linked above):

```
function showWidth(ele, w) {
    $("someDiv").text("The width for the " + ele + 
                " is " + w + "px.");
}

$('#someElement').change(function () { 
  showWidth("document", $(document).width()); 
});
```

Of course, the same applies to height(). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize=function(){
    exampleFunction();
}
```

is what I do. I am not very keen of onchange, if you changed the element with JS, you can also call the event in the same JS. (why do it like: JS -> element -> JS, when you can go: JS -> element and JS)